# how to only fill in only my activecell used during array print?

Tags: excel, vba

I an array that prints new values from one sheet to another (source-to-destination sheet) based on only the unique rows I want to update, it doesn't touch rows with unique keys not specified off source sheet.

The code is doing an offset and updating every other row after where it matches the `rIterator` variable. It works great, but how would I have it fill in the cell with the `RGB(255,255,0)` color index while it's printing the new values?

I would like something like: `activecell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)` somewhere in this for/next loop:

```
For i = 0 To 4 'how many rows to execute multplr array
    For j = 3 To 5 'how many columns to execute multplr array
        wsA.Cells(fndRow + i + 1, j + 47).Value = rIterator.Offset(, j - 1).Value * multplr(i) 'multiple wage by multplr array
    Next j 'next column
    i = i + 1
Next i 'next row
```

Rest of code:

```
Sub UpdateTSRS()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wsA As Worksheet, wsB As Worksheet
Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range
Dim rIterator As Range
Dim fndRow As Long
Dim multplr As Variant
multplr = Array(1, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.3)

Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
Set wsA = wbk.Sheets("Hourly")
Set wsB = wbk.Sheets("New Hourly")
Set rngA = wsA.Range(wsA.Range("E6"), wsA.Range("E6").End(xlDown))
Set rngB = wsB.Range(wsB.Range("A2"), wsB.Range("A2").End(xlDown))

For Each rIterator In rngB 'for each job code in source sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    fndRow = Application.Match(rIterator.Value, rngA, 0) + _
        rngA.Range("E1").Row - 1 'find jobcodes in destination sheet
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Else
    For i = 0 To 4 'how many rows to execute multplr array
        For j = 3 To 5 'how many columns to execute multplr array
            wsA.Cells(fndRow + i + 1, j + 47).Value = rIterator.Offset(, j - 1).Value * multplr(i) 'multiple wage by multplr array
        Next j 'next column
        i = i + 1
    Next i 'next row
    End If
    Err.Clear
Next rIterator 'next job code

End Sub
```

Comment: You want to paint , wsa.Cell or riterator ?

Comment: `wsa.Cell` the active one that the array is printing the new values to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a variable range , set that to your cell , and change that interior color!

if i missunderstood you , just swap the code

```
 Set c = wsA.Cells(fndRow + i + 1, j + 47)
```

uncomment that and comment the next line

```
Dim c As Range

For i = 0 To 4 'how many rows to execute multplr array
    For j = 3 To 5 'how many columns to execute multplr array
        Set c = wsA.Cells(fndRow + i + 1, j + 47)
        'Set c = rIterator.Offset(, j - 1)
        c.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(255, 255, 0)
        wsA.Cells(fndRow + i + 1, j + 47).Value = rIterator.Offset(, j - 1).Value * multplr(i) 'multiple wage by multplr array
    Next j 'next column
    i = i + 1
Next i 'next row
```

Did i helped you ?

Comment: quick question that's related. in my code you see that array starts printing in the row +1 where it finds the `rIterator`, any idea why it's not doing that +1 offset for all 5 multipliers in my `multplr = Array(1, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.3)
`? seems to stop printing the array value * multplr value after the 3rd one

Comment: For i = 0 To 4 'how many rows to execute multplr array
        For j = 3 To 5 'how many columns to execute multplr array
            wsA.Cells(fndRow + i + 1, j + 47).Value = rIterator.Offset(, j - 1).Value * multplr(i) 'multiple wage by multplr array
        Next j 'next column
        i = i + 1
    Next i 'next row

u dont need i = i + 1 , EXCLUDE THAT lINE! And like here